# Haskell list of list of chars adding to tuple

Tags: string, list, haskell

example original `(41.12, [1,2,3,0])`

```
name = ["pete","ben","bill","bob"]
```

example output   `(41.12, [1,2,3,0], ["ben","bill","bob","pete"])`

code so far:

```
getnames :: (Double, [Int]) -> (Double, [Int] -> [[Char]])
getnames ( nil , []) = error "List is empty"
getnames xs = [(doublevalue , listofints, listofstrings))  | x <- xs]
```

How do i use the int list to get a value from the name list and put it in the tuple (i know when i add this to the tulle it isn't a tuple anymore)

What method would i use to do this?

Comment: what have you tried? Any ideas? Do you know a function/operator that gives you an element of your list based on the index? If not can you write one?

Comment: Your type signature right now says "take an ordered pair containing a double and a list of ints and return an ordered pair containing a double and a function from a list of ints to a list of strings". What are you trying to accomplish here exactly?

Comment: If you're trying to make a tuple with a variable size, that's not possible.

Comment: **Hint**: [use Hoogle to find something like `[a] -> Int -> a`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Int+-%3E+a)

Comment: thanks guys already found the answer

Comment: @HopefulSplash ok - you should either edit and answer your question or delete it then - thanks

Comment: getnames :: (Double, [Int]) -> (Double, [Int],[[Char]]) 
    getnames ( nil , []) = error "List is empty"
    getnames xs = (fst xs , snd xs, [city_Name_Array !! p| p<-(snd xs)] )

have the wrong declaration but used to !! operator

Comment: yeah this should work but you should rather use pattern matching instead of `fst` and `snd`: `getnames (dbl, js) = (dbl, js, [... | j <- js])`

Comment: The OP does no longer need the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator `(!!)` can be used to index a list. Given a pair, you can use something along the lines of:

```
getnames :: (Double, [Int]) -> [String] -> (Double, [Int], [String])
getnames (dbl, ixes) names = 
    let namesLst = map (names !!) ixes in
    (dbl, ixes, namesLst)
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1eaf1a654481e138)</kbd>

To get what you want, I've fixed your signature to be able to pass the names and fixed the return value type (which was returning a triple with a function at the end). Also notice that `[Char]` and `String` are exactly the same type.

So inside the body of the function you have `dbl` which is your double and is directly forwarded to the final triple. Then you have `ixes` which are the indexes of the elements you have to take from `ixes`.

At this point we calculate the `namesLst` by mapping the index function over the indexes to get the names in the correct order. Once we have this list, we just have to put it in the third element of the triple.

If you want it to fail on empty index list (even if the names list is empty) then you can add:

```
getnames (_, []) _ = error "..."
```

where `_` means "I don't care enough to name this argument". And can be seen as a placeholder for an argument you'll not use.

Comment: nice - +1 for the live-demo alone - never saw this before - thanks for demonstrating :D